# What is the connection between double commutant theorem and group representation theory?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, group-theory, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the double commutant theorem in the context of group representations.

Googling for "double commutant theorem" I mostly get results about $*$-algebras and von Neumann's bicommutant theorem. For example the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_bicommutant_theorem), and [these pdf notes](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Enspronk/math810/vNdct.pdf).

However, I've also seen in other references the double commutant theorem discussed as a way to get a canonical decomposition of a vector space in terms of irreps of a finite group. In particular, in [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/the-double-commutant-theorem/), as well as in section II of [arXiv:2212.14340](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.14340).

I'm not very well-versed on $*$-algebra things. Are these two approaches one and the same? Does the discussion in terms of $*$-algebras reduces to the one in terms of irreps of some group, or are they different results? Also, what are some standard references discussing the double commutant theorem from the group theory perspective?

Comment: There is also a double commutant theorem for central simple algebras, which is relevant in the representation theory of finite groups.

Comment: See, for example, the book *Associative Algebras* by Pierce: there you will find the double commutant theorem for CSA un detail.